# Words containing 2 overlapping standalone words

Tags: orthography, compounds

I'm looking for words that contain at least two other overlapping words. Word category or origin do not matter (in particular, constituent and containing terms may differ in these regards). Of course, convincing arguments why this quest is in vain or will only produce esoteric results are welcome, too, as are hints to suitable resources.

Background: work related to full text queries of a specialized search engine.

Examples:
Obviously, I haven't come up with any. `grapefruit bat` would be a candidate if it would exist ...

Comment: What about portmanteaus? like *brunch (breakfast + lunch)* and *Eurasia (Europe + Asia).*

Comment: No portmanteaus.

Comment: Superficially, a *teaspoonful*, for example, has ***spoon*** "overlapping" across *teaspoon* and *spoonful*. But that's a single word, whereas OP's hypothetical *grapefruit bat* would be two words anyway. I'm not clear what exactly is being asked for here.

Comment: Are you looking for words like _baleful_ where _bale_ and _ale_ overlap? If yes, I'm sure there are plenty, but I am _not_ sure this site is the right place to construct such a list...

Comment: do the two overlapping words have to then make up the entire word?  If not there's going to be thousands of examples

Comment: In fact, there's thousands of examples even IF those two overlapping words have to make up the entire word

Comment: @GoldenDragon The constituent words need not make up the entire word.

Comment: @oerkelens Sorry, I've been too imprecise: None of the constituent words should contain the other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm no native speaker (surprise), I was told that _fruit bat_ is actually considered a compound noun regardless of its spelling as two lexemes. Anyway, _teaspoonful_  represents the pattern I was looking for.

Comment: I think the question will probably be closed, because there is no "right" answer (just *lists*, of indeterminate length). But you should still make it clear whether what you're looking for is specifically *single-word* forms (what about multi-word or hyphenated expressions?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The basic answer is whether the searched pattern exists at all. The veracity of this kind of answer should not be harder to determine than that of most other language-related questions. I have no clue what 'multi-word _words_' are supposed to be. _hyphenated expressions_ are perfectly acceptable if they are considered a 'word' (assuming that this decision is trivial). Other conceivable answers might provide pointers to lexeme compilations or software frameworks. Frankly, I fear that I don't really understand your comment since I'm just rephrasing my question.

Comment: The decision about whether or not some text sequence represents a "word" is far from trivial. But, for example, ***fruit bat*** is generally written as two words separated by a space, whereas ***batshit***  is normally written as a single word without even a hyphen. And although I doubt you'll find the first "word" in any dictionary (yet?!), most people would probably say [***fruitbatshit** crazy*](http://www.theawl.com/2010/04/the-tea-party-is-as-depressing-as-it-is-predictable) is two words, not four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some triple compound words that are overlapping double compound words:

**backwoodsman** - backwoods and woodsman
**crossbowman** - crossbow and bowman
**overlordship** - overlord and lordship

but what about words like **fate** - fat and ate? Is this really an interesting problem, or one best suited for a computer search?